# gsub with grepl together

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I want to extract part of a string but with an if condition. So that I dont extract anything if this if condition is true.

my code sofar

```
u<-c("18 ABC TEST1 17","ABC 18")

u<-ifelse((grepl("(TEST2|TEST1|)",u,perl=T)==F)&(grepl("^(.*) ?([A-Z]+) ?(.*)",u,perl=T)==T) ,"\\1 \\2",u))
```

So far I got

```
c("18 ABC TEST1 17","\\1 \\2")
```

But i want

```
c("18 ABC TEST1 17","ABC")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you want to extract but following will help you get started.

`grepl` will return vector of boolean values based on which `ifelse` will element-wise choose from vector `u` or vector resulting from `gsub("^(.*) ?([A-Z]+) ?(.*)", "\\1 \\2", u)`

```
ifelse((grepl("(TEST2|TEST1)", u, perl = T)), u, gsub("^(.*) ?([A-Z]+) ?(.*)", "\\1 \\2", u))
## [1] "18 ABC TEST1 17" "AB C"
```